# Is there a way to restrict user to update column further if it has one of the allowable value

Tags: sql-server, constraints, database-trigger

I am looking for a way to restrict user to update a column if it has already a certain value (from allowable value) in SQL Server table.

Say column1 has constrain to allow only one of 'Y' and 'N'
e.g. ([Column1]='N' OR [Column1]='Y')

If the value is 'N' it can be change to 'Y' or 'N'
If the value is 'Y' already then user can not update the column to 'N'

What constraint can be apply to simulate this behavior ? 
Is there a way to use check constraint for this or update trigger is the only way (which I am exploring but not sure is that the correct way to achieve this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do this with a `CONSTRAINT`, no. A `CONSTRAINT` "cares" about the value a column is being set to, not what it was. An `INSTEAD OF` trigger would seem like the better option here.

This is overly simplified, but you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_NoYToN ON dbo.YourTable
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS

    UPDATE YT
    SET SomeColumn = i.SomeColumn,
        AnotherColumn = i.AnotherColumn,
        YourYNColumn = CASE WHEN YT.YourYNColumn = 'Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE i.YourYNColumn END
        ...
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN dbo.inserted i ON YT.YourIDColumn = i.YourIDColumn;
GO
```

You could, I suppose, also use an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to "undo" the change, which would be easier to write, but would require 2 writes on the table for effected rows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_StopYtoN ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS

    UPDATE YT
    SET YourYNColumn = 'Y'
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN deleted d ON YT.YourIDColumn = d.YourIDColumn
    WHERE d.YourYNColumn = 'Y'
      AND YT.YourYNColumn = 'N';
GO
```

Comment: I wouldn't change *anything* automatically except raise an error. If it's not allowed - tell the user. Making changes like this just makes the bugs harder to find.